# How can I span a number of grid cells to create an irregular layout, only using one class (for a post feed module)?

Tags: html, css, css-grid, dynamic-columns

I want to style a post feed module (Divi theme) so that the first column is 50% width and the rest of the 7 are 25%, creating a grid like this https://www.screencast.com/t/GNJODhIG3

I have this CSS grid code so far, but I can't find a way of editing it to get the desired layout.

```
.ds-grid-blog .et_pb_ajax_pagination_container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 18%);
    grid-column-gap: 2.5%;
}
```

Is there some code I could add like "column-one, row-one: 50%;"

Comment: Show all the code you've tried (including the HTML). We can help you more effectively if we can reproduce the problem.

Comment: ^ Specifically, a [mcve] is required.

Comment: http://mediaworldwide.co.uk/perfect-storm/ams-test-site/news/

Comment: Sorry, yes that would help, see link above.. Thanks

Comment: This code works to a point, but it focusses on all the first columns in all rows, I am trying just to focus on the first column on the first row, so independent of all other rows and columns.... .bloggrid-no-excerpts-news-test .column.size-1of3:nth-child(1) { width: 47.667% !important; }

Comment: I have tried many formulas, but I can't focus on just the one, I know nth-child has a parent/child relatio ship, so I've tried to focus on .wrap which is where all the text elements are, and also article, but no luck yet...  My page is 
mediaworldwide.co.uk/perfect-storm/ams-test-site/news  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

With grid, if you intend to divide into n-columns, it is no longer necessary (and is actually an anti-pattern) to calculate the percentages yourself, it is better to use `fr` units, which divide the free space into fractions. In addition, what you are trying to achieve requires setting a css rule that says "first child of the container should span two rows". An example of a possible solution is shown below:

```css
    .container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
    grid-column-gap: 2.5%;
    grid-row-gap: 2.5%;
}
.container > :first-child {
  grid-column: 1 / 3;
}
.box {
  background-color: grey;

}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="box">1</div>
<div class="box">2</div>
<div class="box">3</div>
<div class="box">4</div>
<div class="box">5</div>
<div class="box">6</div>
<div class="box">7</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for this Piotr Wicijowski... Unfortunately I can only assign one class or ID to the module (post feed)?!  See here http://mediaworldwide.co.uk/perfect-storm/ams-test-site/news/

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand how exactly the url you posted would give an example of what you are trying to get. Please be more specific on what are your requirements, what markup you have and why the solution cannot be adjusted to your needs. Finally, my solution has only one class assigned to the container (.container) and one to the "module" (.box).

Comment: I don't think CSS grid will work as I only have one class, so I'm going to close this thread and start a new one re nth-child... Thanks for your help.

Comment: Sorry  Piotr Wicijowski, I've just tried your answer,, it's had some effect but I'm not sure if I've set it up correctly... I have a section which I added "bloggrid-no-excerpts-news-test" to, and a post module which I've added "ds-grid-blog" to, here is my code..... .bloggrid-no-excerpts-news-test { display: grid; grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr); grid-column-gap: 2.5%; grid-row-gap: 2.5%; }
.bloggrid-no-excerpts-news-test > :first-child { grid-column: 1 / 3; }
.ds-grid-blog { background-color: grey; width: 47.667% !important; } ...What do you think? Thanks

Comment: I can't find the class `.bloggrid-no-excerpts-news-test` on your mediaworldwide.co.uk site, so it is hard for me to visualize, where you put it. In addition, you have a very deeply nested div structure, so using ` > :first-child` will not work, as the cards are not direct children of the container.

Comment: Thanks @Piotr Wicijowski. I agree, don't think it will work with nth child. I will try looking at using JavaScript.

Comment: It can work if you assign the classes correctly - in the end, even in a very nested structure there has to be a div that would be a container holding all your modules/cards. If the :first-child selector is the issue here, you can always modify the selector a bit and switch to :first-of-type.

Comment: Okay thanks.. I think I need to learn more about nested structures.